# Converting a float into a timespan

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

Is there a simple way to take a `float` value representing fractional hours and convert them into a `TimeSpan` object and visa versa? For example:

```
float oneAndAHalfHours = 1.5f;
float twoHours = 2f;
float threeHoursAndFifteenMinutes = 3.25f;
float oneDayAndTwoHoursAndFortyFiveMinutes = 26.75f;

TimeSpan myTimeSpan = ConvertToTimeSpan(oneAndAHalfHours); // Should return a TimeSpan Object
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You want the [`FromHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx) method.

This takes a double (rather than a float) and returns a `TimeSpan`:

```
double hours = 1.5;
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours);
```

To get the total hours from a `TimeSpan` use the [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) property:

```
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(1, 15, 42, 45, 750);
double hours = interval.TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 12):

So, you're looking for... [TimeSpan.FromHours(double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx)?

The documentation is your friend.

Comment: That naming scheme's just crazy. So undiscoverable. Who'd have thought that if I wanted to create a `TimeSpan` *from* a number of *hours*, that that's what `TimeSpan.FromHours` would do?

Comment: I would pay good money to see a date/time API designed by Eric. I actually mean that entirely literally... I think the value I'd gain in comparing his decisions to the ones I've taken in Noda Time would be worth quite a bit to me.

Comment: Indeed, it should be `TimeSpan.FromThreePointSixMillionMilliseconds` to make sense.

Comment: ToHours() - would have been some form of improvement, to say "FromHours" infers that you are doing something from an hours value.

Comment: @Vidar: Except it's a static method, so `ToHours(hours)` makes no sense.  `ToXXX` only really makes sense as an instance method. *"'FromHours' infers that you are doing something from an hours value.* - It *implies* that, yes, because that's exactly what it is doing. You provide the hours, it returns a `TimeSpan`